# Unset one Array on the basis of another array value in php?

Tags: php, unset, array-unset

How can I remove one array index on the basis of another array value.
For example-

```
Array1
(
[0] => @@code
[1] => @@label
[2] => @@name
[3] => @@age
)

Array2
(
[0] => 123jj
[1] => test
[2] => john
[3] => 45
)

Array3
(
[0] => 2 #2 is index to be unset in array1 and array2
[1] => 3 #3 is index to be unset in array1 and array2
)
```

I have  3 arrays , I want to unset array1 and array2 index on the basis of value of array3 using php.How can I use unset() Method for this?

```
unset($array1,$array3) #this is wrong, but some thing like that 
unset($array2,$array3)
```

**With Out for loop.**

I should get

```
Array1
(
[0] => @@code
[1] => @@label
)

Array2
(
[0] => 123jj
[1] => test
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked similar question and removed it after getting the answer :

[unset array indexs from value of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485543/unset-array-indexs-from-value-of-another-array)

```
$firstArray = array( 0 => '@@code' ,1 => '@@label' ,2 => '@@name' ,3 => '@@age' );

$keysArray = array( 0 ,1 );

$resultArray = array_diff_key( $firstArray ,array_flip( $keysArray ) );

var_dump( $resultArray );
```

Comment: Was it the same guy? I took my time to write a very nice answer, only to discover the question had been deleted :(

Comment: @Nic I was looking at the profile of OP of that question and found this question !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this?

```
foreach($array3 as $tmp){
  unset($array1[$tmp]);
  unset($array2[$tmp]);
}
```

Comment: I want it with out using for loop. Some thing like

unset($array1,$array3)
unset($array2,$array3)