# unset array indexs from value of another array?

Tags: php

I want to unset array indexs using [unset](http://www.php.net/unset) in php.

```
<?php
$a=array('a','b','c','d','e');
$b=array(2,3);//2,3 are indexs which I have to unset from array a.
print_r($a);
unset($a,$b);//how can I do it.
print_r($a);
?>
```

I want output like: **With out Iterate over $b and unset($a[$b_value]);**

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e ) 
Array ([0] => a [1] => b [4] => e )
```

Comment: Iterate over `$b` and `unset($a[$b_value]);`

Comment: I dont want to iterate as I have script and huge data . so it will take more time.

Comment: How big can `$a` and `$b` get?

Comment: @oecPrashant Tests shows that simple iteration takes less time in case of huge data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for oneline solution try this:

```
$a = array_diff_key($a, array_flip($b));
```

Also I wrote the performance test [(source)](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/ForeachVsArrayDiff.php) for this algorithm. It faster than
`foreach($b as $val) unset($a[$val]);` by 20-30%.

**Update**

Seems this algorithm have non-linear performance dependency from data amount:

**`$a` with 1000 elements result:**

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
array_diff_key  10000           0.990571 sec    +0.00%
foreach         10000           1.183903 sec    -19.52%
```

**`$a` with 10000 elements result:**

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
foreach         10000           12.924521 sec   +0.00%
array_diff_key  10000           28.338741 sec   -119.26%
```

**`$a` with 100000 elements result:**

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
foreach         10000           201.961125 sec  +0.00%
array_diff_key  10000           619.329440 sec  -206.66%
```

If `$a` array have more than 1000 elements i would prefer `foreach` algorithm.

Comment: Nice work . Useful to know that `foreach` is considerably efficient in case of large arrays .

Comment: great  @Alexander Yancharuk.Thanks for your very brilliant advice.

Answer (score 0):

**array_diff_key**

```
<?php
$a=array('a','b','c','d','e');
$b=array(0,1);//0,1 are indexs which I have to unset from array a.
print_r($a);
$a = array_diff_key ($a,$b);//how can I do it.
print_r($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=array('a','b','c','d','e');
$b=array(2,3);//2,3 are indexs which I have to unset from array a.
print_r($a);
$c = removeFromAnotherArray($a,$b);
print_r($c);
function removeFromAnotherArray($a,$b)
{
    foreach($b as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$a))
        {
            unset($a[$val]);
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [4] => e
)
```